# why my variable does not work with sed command to delete lines with patterns?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with duplicated lines.

```
FrameNO Title Rule: Frame# time(fs) CN [Qn] LabelOfTargetType (PRMRYTGT or SBSDRYTGT) TargetAtomID  TargetAtomName  NeighborAtomID    NeighborAtomName  BondLenght  NeighborAtomID  ...
FRAM_#            0            0(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT     16653      H    16652      O  0.988
  CN= 0 SBSDRYTGT     16652      O     16654      H  0.942     16653      H  0.988
    CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     16654      H     16652      O  0.942
FrameNO Title Rule: Frame# time(fs) CN [Qn] LabelOfTargetType (PRMRYTGT or SBSDRYTGT) TargetAtomID  TargetAtomName  NeighborAtomID    NeighborAtomName  BondLenght  NeighborAtomID  ...
FRAM_#          100           25(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT     16653      H    16652      O  0.959
  CN= 0 SBSDRYTGT     16652      O     16654      H  1.012     16653      H  0.959
    CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     16654      H     16652      O  1.012
FrameNO Title Rule: Frame# time(fs) CN [Qn] LabelOfTargetType (PRMRYTGT or SBSDRYTGT) TargetAtomID  TargetAtomName  NeighborAtomID    NeighborAtomName  BondLenght  NeighborAtomID  ...
FRAM_#          200           50(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT     16653      H    16652      O  0.991
  CN= 0 SBSDRYTGT     16652      O     16654      H  0.952     16653      H  0.991
......
```

I want to use variable to delete those duplicated lines
`FrameNO Title Rule: Frame# time(fs) CN [Qn] LabelOfTargetType (PRMRYTGT or SBSDRYTGT) TargetAtomID  TargetAtomName  NeighborAtomID    NeighborAtomName  BondLenght  NeighborAtomID  ..`

Following are my commands:

```
key=`head -n 1 filename`; 
sed -i "/$key/d" filename;
```

I expect to get results like below

```
FRAM_#            0            0(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT     16653      H    16652      O  0.988
  CN= 0 SBSDRYTGT     16652      O     16654      H  0.942     16653      H  0.988
    CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     16654      H     16652      O  0.942
FRAM_#          100           25(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT     16653      H    16652      O  0.959
  CN= 0 SBSDRYTGT     16652      O     16654      H  1.012     16653      H  0.959
    CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     16654      H     16652      O  1.012
FRAM_#          200           50(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT     16653      H    16652      O  0.991
  CN= 0 SBSDRYTGT     16652      O     16654      H  0.952     16653      H  0.991
    CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     16654      H     16652      O  0.952
FRAM_#          300           75(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT     16653      H    16652      O  0.952
  CN= 0 SBSDRYTGT     16652      O     16654      H  0.987     16653      H  0.952
    CN= 1 SBSDRYTGT     16654      H     16652      O  0.987
.......
```

However, the commands above does NOT work. If I use

```
sed -i '/FrameNO/d' filename;
```

I can get the correct result.

I tried to set the variable

```
keyword=FrameNO
```

and I could not get the correct result.

May I know what is going wrong when using a variable? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the variable. It's the special characters that are the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line contains `[]` characters, which have special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape them so they'll be matched literally.

```
key=$(head -n 1 filename)
key=${key//\[/\\[}
key=${key//\]/\\]}
```

`${variable//pattern/replacement}` replaces all matches of the wildcard `pattern` with `replacement` in the value of `$variable`.

But instead of using `sed`, you can use `grep -F`, which performs exact matching instead of matching a regular expression. Then you don't need to do the above replacements.

```
grep -v -F "$key" filename > filename.new && mv filename.new filename
```

Comment: If I use your way to set key, and then use sed -i "/$key/d" filename can get all duplicated lines removed. If I use grep command, not all duplicated lines can be removed. But I appreciate your time and answer.

Comment: I can't see any reason why the duplicated lines aren't removed with `grep`. What do you get instead?

Comment: Some lines have not been deleted. Here, would you please explain to me the meaning of //\[/\\[ which I could not find in the BASH tutorial? Any further information,like source of such trick, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's in the Bash manual in the section on [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `${var//old/new}` replaces all occurrences of `old` with `new` in the value of the variable.

Comment: So it's replacing `[` with `\[`

Comment: It's a relatively advanced technique, not likely to be taught in beginner tutorials.

Comment: If you use `grep` you don't need to escape the special characters in the key, since the `-F` option means to match exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is very helpful and useful!